# DocumentDB Spatial Query - Odd Result

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am fairly new to DocumentDB, I have experience with MongoDB.

This is my simple document:

```
 {
"id": "747941cfb829_1453640096710",
"geometry": {
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        0,
        0
      ],
      [
        10,
        10
      ],
      [
        10,
        0
      ],
      [
        0,
        0
      ]
    ]
  ]
},
"name": "name",
"_rid": "Px12AM4QPgBsAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/Px12AA==/colls/Px12AM4QPgA=/docs/Px12AM4QPgBsAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"07006019-0000-0000-0000-573395f50000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1462998499}
```

And this is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM root r WHERE   ST_WITHIN({'type':'Point','coordinates':[-122.02625, 37.4718]}, r.geometry)
```

When I run this query, it returns the document, but the point is not within the polygon.  Does anyone know what could be going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified your polygon in a clockwise manner which, localized, is interpreted as everything outside of this polygon. If you alter it to be counter-clockwise (shown below), you'll get the expected results.

```
{
  "id": "747941cfb829_1453640096710",
  "geometry": {
  "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          0, 
          0
        ],
        [
          10,
          0
        ],
        [
          10,
          10
        ],
        [
          0,
          0
        ]
      ]
    ]
  },
  "name": "name"
}
```