# Document DB Polygon Query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

My previous question is here [DocumentDB Spatial Query - Odd Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188876/documentdb-spatial-query-odd-result)

Now the query below won't return the document.

```
 SELECT * FROM root r WHERE   ST_WITHIN({'type':'Point','coordinates':[3.5, 8.2]}, r.geometry)
```

This is my amended document:

```
{
"id": "747941cfb829_1453640096710",
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[[0,
    0],
    [10,
    0],
    [10,
    10],
    [0,
    0]]]
},
"name": "name"}
```

How do I return this document? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your polygon is a triangle and the point you specify in your query is outside of that triangle. Try [8.2, 3.5].

Comment: Thanks Larry.  I am definitely on a DocumentDB learning curve.

Comment: I was there about a year ago. It's a great product. The differences from other data storage choices both makes is uniquely valuable and a bit harder to learn as you reprogram your thinking. You'll get there. :-)